# How can i find product by its objectID using algolia search?

Tags: json, search-engine, algolia

Say me please, how can i find product from json datafile by its objectID?

I tried do this:

```
helper.addNumericRefinement('numericAttribute', '=', '3').search();
```

I tried replace 'numericAttribute' to 'objectID' but it was not work. When i pasted 'price' instead 'numericAttribute' it was work good and search found results by price.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you would like to retrieve only one product at the time, you could use the [getObject method](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js#get-an-object) available in the Algolia JS client.

```
index.getObject('myObjectID', function(err, content) {
   console.log(content.objectID + ": " + content.toString());
})
```

Otherwise if your objectID are numerical values and you want to retrieve several products (= records) at the same time, then the best approach is probably to put the objectID value to a new attribute (that could be called `productId`), and then perform the same search as you did, but on that new attribute.

```
helper.addNumericRefinement('productId', '=', '3').search();`
```

Comment: Algolia also supports `getObjects` so you can avoid fiddling with numeric refinements like so:

`index.getObjects(['myObj1', 'myObj2'], function(err, content) {
  console.log(content);
});`

Comment: I'm seeing `TypeError: index.getObject is not a function` in the console error?